# Como enviar um Array via POST para um controller PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, array

Preciso passar um array via POST para meu controller PHP, a única forma que tenho em mente é não passar um array, mas passar as informações por um separador(, ; |), porém não queria ter que ficar dando explode do outro lado(Controller).

No momento estou fazendo o seguinte, Javascript:

```
 var listaEnvioArray = new Array();
 var item = new Array();
 item["id"] = 1;
 item["descricao"] = "teste";
 listaEnvioArray.push(item);

 $.post(basepath + "perfil/meuController", {
    array : listaEnvioArray
    }, function(dados) {    
        // TODO ação
    });
```

No meu controller estou recuperando dessa forma(CodeIgniter):

```
$dados['array'] = $this->input->post('array');
```

Porém o mesmo chega vazio aqui.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O problema está no JavaScript aqui:

```
var item = new Array();
item["id"] = 1;
item["descricao"] = "teste";
```

Você definiu um *array*  mas está usando como se fosse um objeto/hash. Faça assim:

```
var item = {};
item["id"] = 1;
item["descricao"] = "teste";
```

Ou assim:

```
var item = { id: 1, descricao: "teste" };
```

---

*Array* em JavaScript não é igual a PHP. Você não pode usar chaves alfa-numéricas. Somente objetos podem ter propriedades que são texto ("id", "descricao"). Em JavaScript, *Arrays* só possuem chaves numéricas, e não podemos interferir nelas livremente como podemos no PHP.

Comment: Valeeu, vou testar amanhã no trabalho

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Eu passaria os dados como objeto mesmo, e recuperaria eles no PHP com a função `json_decode()` transformando-os em array do php.