# array em javascript que se comunique em php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, array

Preciso criar um `array` em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) que se envie suas informações para uma página [php](/questions/tagged/php).

Como posso fazer isso?

Seguinte, eu tinha uma pg em [php](/questions/tagged/php) que carregava, muitos dados repetidos do banco.
Então para melhora o desempenho dela, criei um script em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) que copiava o conteúdos das tabelas.
Porém cada tabela tem uma `option` e cada `option` tem um `selected`, logo preciso que cada `option` comece como sua frase específica, igual era a pg toda em [php](/questions/tagged/php). Para isso fiz o script abaixo:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // frase que desejo localizar
    var frase      = "minAlarme4_analogico00",
        localizado = null;

    // loop que percorre cada uma das opções
    // e verifica se a frase da opção confere com o
    // valor de fase que está sendo procurado
    // valor de fase que está sendo procurado
    $('#Linha5 option').each(function() {
      // se localizar a frase, define o atributo selected
      if($(this).attr('value') == frase) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

Porém (minAlarme4_analogico00") é o nome de um sensor e eu tenho tipo uns 1500.
Então preciso que um array se comunique com o [php](/questions/tagged/php) para que o mesmo pegue os nomes dos sensores.

Comment: Você precisa que seja algo dinâmico, tipo AJAX ou quer enviar informações de um formulário utilizando POST ou GET e ao atualizar a página atualizar estes dados? Você está utilizando jQuery ou prefere uma resposta com JS puro?

Comment: Não entendi, poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Você conhece código para lidar com Arrays em JavaScript? http://imasters.com.br/artigo/21197/javascript/entendendo-arrays-no-javascript/

Comment: Olá gabriel Gartz, preciso de algo dinamico. :D

Comment: Fiz essa pergunta esses dias, talvez este link te ajude : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/7667/como-enviar-um-array-via-post-para-um-controller-php

Comment: @user5946, você precisa utilizar ajax para isso.
Qual a finalidade desta comunicação, explique melhor o problema e podemos te dar um caminho.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o `JSON.stringify(array)` no JavaScript para codificar o array e envia-lo para o PHP, onde vc usa `$array = json_decode($_POST['dados']);` para ler a variável passada.

Caso deseje realizar algo dinamicamente, você deve utilizar [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), o que daria em algo mais ou menos assim:

**No JS**

```
meuArray = ??? ;
var arrayCodificado = JSON.stringify(meuArray);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: { dados: arrayCodificado }, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(){
        alert("Feito!");
    }
});
```

**No PHP**

```
$meuArray = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['dados']));
foreach($meuArray as $d){
    echo $d;
}
```

Comment: Desative o `magic_quotes_gpc` no seu PHP.

Comment: Bom dia. KrasH o que iria exatamente aqui nessa linha de codigo?(meuArray = ??? ;)