# Array em PHP que se comunique com JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, array

Tenho esse programa que coloca o `selected` de acordo com o `value`:

```
<!--inicio if option = selected-->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // frase que desejo localizar (pega o value do option )
    var frase      = "minAlarme4_analogico00",
        localizado = null;
    // loop que percorre cada uma das opções
    // e verifica se a frase da opção confere com o
    // valor de fase que está sendo procurado
    // valor de fase que está sendo procurado
    $('#Linha5 option').each(function() {
      // se localizar a frase, define o atributo selected
      if($(this).attr('value') == frase) {
        $(this).prop('selected', true);
      }
    });
});
        </script>

<!--Final if option = selected-->
```

Porém para gerar esses "values" eu tenho um programa que faz isso.
Obs: Infelizmente não posso postar esse código fonte e na verdade nem tenho acesso ao mesmo.

Mas tenho o seguinte conteúdo nos "values" do código que tenho acesso. O "value" esta assim `value=\"%s\"%s>%s`. Exemplo:

```
printf("<option value=\"%s\"%s>%s</option>\n", $nomeScript, $extra, $descricaoScript);.
```

Como criar um array em PHP que se comunique com JavaScript?

<sup>(Anteriormente eu postei uma pergunta falando que precisava do contrário, mas como os dados vem do banco de dados acho que eu preciso que o array seja em PHP para passar os valores para o JavaScript).</sup>

Comment: Tem como explicar melhor o objetivo final dessa estratégia? O que você quer fazer com isso? Porque se você quiser apenas converter uma array de PHP pra usar no javascript, basta usar a função `json_encode` nativa do php.

Comment: [Duplicada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8106/array-em-javascript-que-se-comunique-em-php)?

Comment: @GabrielGartz,olá.
É o seguinte eu tinha uma pagina em php que puxava o varios conteudos do banco de dados e gerava varias tabelas, porém todas as tabelas tem o mesmo conteudo o que diferencia 1 das outras é o seguinte o "Value" e a primeira frase que se inicia.
Então fiz o seguinte:1° Criei um script de copia;

Comment: @GabrielGartz Continuando:2° Fiz um script para mudar o "selecteds" assim consegui uma frase em cada tabela conformo era o código acima.
Ate ai td bem, porém quando mostrei por meu tutor ele disse, vc não pode passar os "Values" assim.
Quero que vc faça o seguinte crie um array e faça o php se comunicar com javascript para passar os "values" dinamicamente.

Infelizmente não sei explicar melhor, pois é meu primeiro contato com programação e estou tendo muita dificuldade como vcs devem ter notado.Se ficou mais claro e poder me ajudar grata.

Comment: @perdeu, Não é Duplicata, no outro poste eu queria um array em javascript que se comunicasse com php, porém eu pensei melhor e concluir. Se quero pegar os dados do banco no array, preciso fazer o array em php se comunicar com javascript.

Comment: O que eu ainda não entendi é qual o objetivo da array do PHP que vc vai passar pro Javascript, tipo você já gerou os options e já sabe como selecionar, o que essa array que vem do PHP vai dar de informação ao seu javascript? Qual o propósito dela?

Comment: @GabrielGartz, Olá Então ele quer que eu pegue os valores dos values dinamicamente. Eu tmb não consigo entender pq ele quer isso :(

Comment: Pegar valores dinamicamente é algo muito vago, precisa existir um propósito pra isso, ao que parece você está listando as opções e selecionando uma e isso deve implicar na próxima ação da sua aplicação que é baixar a tabela correspondente e exibir na página. Se você está baixando todas as tabelas e apenas escondendo as que não estão sendo usadas, talvez o que ele queira é que baixe apenas a que está sendo exibida. Mas isso é um chute porque a descrição como um todo é muito vaga.

Comment: @GabrielGartz, Então ele quer o seguinte que eu pegue as frases dinamicamente que vão aparecer na primeira linha da tabela e faça um array com elas.

Comment: Jessi seu caso vai um pouco além do que converter uma array do PHP pra Javascript, pois talvez isso sequer seja necessário nesse estagio da sua aplicação, o que ele quer é que você filtre os dados no lado do servidor, depois entregue o minimo necessário (value) pro cliente e quando este selecionar uma "option" carregue o resto dos dados.

Comment: Não sei como é a sua estrutura no PHP, mas o provavel é que esses dados estejam vindo da base de dados e te retornando um dicionário, você vai ter que fazer um novo dicionário a partir do original contendo apenas os dados relevantes. Como seu conhecimento é limitado acho que até a explicação formal se torna complexa, o mais fácil seria expor seu código no lado do servidor para que possamos ajuda-la.

Comment: É Jessi, está muito difícil entender onde você quer chegar. O Gabriel tem boas hipóteses, mas não sei se ele tem razão. Você pode explicar o contexto mais amplo da sua tarefa? Você está digitando algo num campo e marcando um valor no select conforme o que foi digitado? Se for, estranho isso, pois selects geralmente são para escolher um valor de uma lista, não digitando.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi, você quer enviar um array em PHP para o Javascript entender.

Netse caso você poderia utiliar a função [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php) para enviar um `JSON` para o JavaScript.

Exemplo:

```
echo json_encode(["a" => 10, "b" => 20, "c" => 30])
#vai imprimir {"a": 10, "b": 20, "c": 30}
```