# Passar dados do javascript para um array em php

Tags: javascript, php, array

Tenho um pequeno problema que gostaria de algumas idéias para solucionar:

Tenho uma tela de pedidos, onde seleciono o produto numa combo, informo a quantidade e ao clicar num botão, quero inserir os dados do value do combo e o value da quantidade em algum array javascript, exibir em uma table logo abaixo e inserir estes dados em um array php para quando for salvar o pedido, poder varrer este array em php e salvar os dados no banco.

Existe uma forma de fazer isso que seja simples?

Complementando a pergunta:

Uso atualmente as bibliotecas jQuery e meu sistema é feito em CodeIgniter. O Array em PHP eu manteria na view mesmo e passaria como parametro para o Controller quando fosse salvar tudo no banco.

Atualmente utilizo um Ajax para buscar o preço do produto do banco sem dar o refresh, então a parte de buscar dados do banco com ajax eu já consigo me virar, conforme mostro a seguir:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("select[name='produto_id']").change(function () {
        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url();?>';
        alert('Entrou');
        var preco = $("input[name='valor']");
        //var teste = $("select[name='nome']").val();
        //alert(teste);
        $(preco).val('Carregando...');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //url: "application/views/admin/teste.php",
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php?admin/list_dropdown',
            data: "prod=" + $("select[name='produto_id']").val(),
            success: function (json) {
                alert(json);
                //$(preco).val((Math.round(json * 100) / 100)).toFixed(2);
                $(preco).val(json).toFixed(2);
            }
        });
        //);
    });
});
</script>
```

Minha dúvida, ficaria sendo, como pegar estes dados do javascript, adiciona-los em um array em PHP (pois não sei quantos produtos serão selecionados) para depois, ao clicar no botão salvar, eu mandar este array junto para o controller.

Abração!

Comment: Poste a parte do combo e da tela de pedidos, que fica mais fácil ajudar a passar o array que você já tem pro PHP. Não é complicado, mas convém você já deixar até onde chegou publicado com a pergunta.

Comment: Ariel, complete a sua pergunta com mais código e clareza sobre o que pretende (como o Bacco pediu). Esclareça também se o ficheiro de PHP é o mesmo que o ficheiro onde tm o HTML e se usa alguma biblioteca de Javascript como MooTools ou jQuery.

Comment: Adicionalmente, veja se essa é a resposta que procura. Caso seja, pode até deletar a pergunta, caso não seja, passe mais detalhes. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8106/array-em-javascript-que-se-comunique-em-php

Comment: Galerinha, atualizei minha pergunta, acho que ficou mais clara agora...

Answer (score 3):

Como você não deixou claro em qual parte exatamente estava com dificuldade, eu vou deixar um exemplo completo e explicar ele.

Primeiros criamos a seguinte página HTML.

```
<form id="dataForm">
    <select name="type">
        <option value="1">Tipo 1</option>
        <option value="2">Tipo 2</option>
        <option value="3">Tipo 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="value" />
    <input type="submit" value="Adicionar" />
</form>
<input id="submitAll" type="button" value="Enviar" />
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Tipo</th>
        <th>Valor</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Nela temos o formulário HTML que vai ser usado para adicionar itens, temos um outro botão fora do formulário que vai ser usado pelo Javascript para enviar os dados e temos uma table onde vamos exibir os dados que já foram adicionados.

No Javascript nós vamos usar a função `preventDefault` para impedir que o formulário seja enviado normalmente, depois nós pegamos os dados que estão nele e colocamos numa array global e também inserimos ele na tabela.

```
var sendData = [];
$('form#dataForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var type = $('select[name=type] option:selected').val(),
        value = $('input[name=value]').val();
    sendData.push({
        'type': type,
        'value': value
    });
    $('table tr:last').after(
        '<tr>\
            <td>'+type+'</td>\
            <td>'+value+'</td>\
        </tr>');
});
```

Em seguida no botão `submitAll` nós convertemos a array global `sendData` para JSON, limpamos ela e a tabela e ao final enviamos os dados.

```
$('input#submitAll').click(function(){
    var data = JSON.stringify(sendData);
    sendData = [];
    $('table tr:gt(0)').remove();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/insert.php',
        data: 'data=' + data,
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function(ret) {
            document.write('<pre>' + ret +'</pre>');
        }
    });
});
```

Agora no PHP basta você usar a função `json_decode` e trabalhar com a array como desejar. Como é só um exemplo eu vou devolver o `print_r` da array para o Javascript que colocá-lo na página.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data'])) {
    $data = json_decode($_POST['data']);
    print_r($data);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A melhor forma de passar informação Javascript <=> PHP é através de JSON.

No post por `ajax` deve indicar o `dataType: 'json'`.

Do lado do PHP deverá responder em algo como:

```
<?php 
echo json_encode(array('result'=>'hello world'));
?>
```

Por fim, no tratamento da resposta do seu pedido de ajax poderá aceder ao array enviado pelo PHP:

```
success: function (json) {
            alert(json.result);
}
```

Comment: Se quiser enviar um array em Javascript para PHP através de JSON, basta fazer `$arrJs = json_decode($_POST['arr']); `